# Ubuntu Server 20.04 netplan Static IPs dropped after disconnecting

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, netplan, static-ip

I am setting static IP addresses for multiple ethernet ports on a machine using netplan. They work until a cable gets disconnected and then reconnected. When I pull a cable and plug it back in I don't get an IP address on that adapter.

My 00-netcfg.yaml file looks like this. I don't have any other yaml files in `/etc/netplan`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:  # port 1
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.70.1/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.64.5, 192.168.64.13, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      optional: true
    enp10s0: # port 2
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.70.2/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      optional: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.64.5, 192.168.64.13, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    enp11s0:  # port 3
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.70.3/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      optional: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.64.5, 192.168.64.13, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I found a few posts suggesting adding `link-local: []` entries for each adaptor and disabling ipv6 by adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"` in `/etc/default/grub` but no joy. Suggestions gratefully received

Comment: Your IP4 addresses and gateway are not on the same subnet. If you're using an IP address 10.0.70.* and the gateway is 10.0.0.1, your subnet should probably be /16 and not /24. Does this make any difference?

Comment: while there are some inconsistencies in the config (see previous comment), if the network is not coming back up correctly after a link disconnect/reconnect, that sounds like a networkd bug.  Please file a bug using ubuntu-bug systemd.